# Nextjs 13 problem with uploading image to AWS S3

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, next.js

I'm trying to use aws sdk in nextjs to upload images but have consistent problem of receiving error code 403(Forbidden). Is there can be other reasons why I'm getting this error besides invalid accessKeyId and secretAccessKey.
Here basic is code implementation:

```
const s3 = new S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_AWS_REGION,
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});

export const uploadObject = async (
  file: File,
  key: string,
  onProgress: (percent: number) => void,
  onSuccess: () => void,
  onError: () => void
) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_AWS_S3_BUCKET!,
    Key: key,
    Body: file,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: file.type,
  };

  s3.upload(params)
    .on('httpUploadProgress', (evt) => {
      onProgress(Math.ceil((100 * evt.loaded) / evt.total));
    })
    .send((error: any, data: any) => {
      if (error) {
        onError();
      } else {
        onSuccess();
      }
    });
};
```

Is there any problems with my code?

Answer (score 0):

403 means that the authenticated "user" does not have permission to do what you want. In your case, I guess it would be missing privileges either on the bucket or in IAM.

Something like

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1/*"
      }
   ]
}
```